# In normality of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix.
I need a help to show that if ($A^{+}A^{*}$) is isometry partial then $A$ normal

Comment: What do you mean by $A^+$ and $A^\ast$?

Comment: $A^{+}$ is the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse and $A^{*}$ is adjoint of $A$

Comment: To the OP. If the condition you are considering is only a conjecture, then you need to specify it. Otherwise, you are wasting our time studying uninteresting problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Consider the singular value decomposition $A=SV^\ast$ where
$$
S=\pmatrix{1\\ &\frac12\\ &&0\\ &&&0},
\ V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{32}}\pmatrix{4&0&-4&0\\ 2&0&2&\sqrt{24}\\ 3&\sqrt{8}&3&-\sqrt{6}\\ -\sqrt{3}&\sqrt{24}&-\sqrt{3}&\sqrt{2}}.
$$
Then
$$
S^+VS
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{32}}\pmatrix{4&0&0&0\\ 4&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0}
=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&0&0\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0}
$$
and hence $A^+A^\ast=VS^+VS$ is a partial isometry, because
$$
(A^+A^\ast)^\ast (A^+A^\ast)
=(VS^+VS)^\ast(VS^+VS)
=(S^+VS)^\ast(S^+VS)
=\operatorname{diag}(1,0,0,0)
$$
is an orthogonal projection. However, one may verify that
$$
A=SV^\ast
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{32}}\pmatrix{4&2&3&-\sqrt{3}\\ 0&0&\sqrt{2}&\sqrt{6}\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0}
$$
is not normal.

Comment: The singular value decomposition of $A$ is, $A=USV^{*}$. So you take $U=I$ right?

Comment: @Marwa Yes, $U=I$. And $S^+$ is obtained by taking the inverses of the nonzero diagonal elements of $S$. Hence $S^+=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,0,0)$ in this case.

Comment: Okey! Thank you a lot